# npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

When I try to run `npm install` i am getting the following error.

```
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/harshamv/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/harshamv/package.json'
npm WARN harshamv No description
npm WARN harshamv No repository field.
npm WARN harshamv No README data
npm WARN harshamv No license field.

audited 15434 packages in 3.37s
found 1227 vulnerabilities (185 low, 326 moderate, 716 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

My theme file structure is the following

```
template/
   |-- package.json
   |-- GruntFile.js
   |-- assets/
   |   |-- css/
   |   |-- img/
   |   |-- js/
   |   |-- scss/
   |-- libs/
   |   |-- jquery/
   |   |-- bootstrap/
   |   |-- ...
   |-- docs/
   |   |-- index.html
   |   |-- build.html
   |   |-- ...
   |-- html/
   |   |-- dashboard.html
   |   |-- app.user.html
   |   |-- ...
```

Now sure why it's trying to access the package.json from my user directory. when i am trying to run the command from inside the template directory.

This is the Audit Log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'audit' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v10.14.2
4 verbose config Skipping project config: /Users/harshamv/.npmrc. (matches userconfig)
5 verbose npm-session 1bbf94576e91f043
6 verbose stack Error: No package.json found: Cannot audit a project without a package.json
6 verbose stack     at Bluebird.all.spread (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/audit.js:143:19)
6 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
6 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:509:35)
6 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
6 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
6 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromises (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:693:18)
6 verbose stack     at Promise._fulfill (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:638:18)
6 verbose stack     at PromiseArray._resolve (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise_array.js:126:19)
6 verbose stack     at PromiseArray._promiseFulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise_array.js:144:14)
6 verbose stack     at PromiseArray._iterate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise_array.js:114:31)
6 verbose stack     at PromiseArray.init [as _init] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise_array.js:78:10)
6 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:566:21)
6 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
6 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromises (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:693:18)
6 verbose stack     at Promise._fulfill (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:638:18)
6 verbose stack     at PromiseArray._resolve (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise_array.js:126:19)
7 verbose cwd /Users/harshamv/Sites/template
8 verbose Darwin 18.2.0
9 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "audit"
10 verbose node v10.14.2
11 verbose npm  v6.4.1
12 error code EAUDITNOPJSON
13 error audit No package.json found: Cannot audit a project without a package.json
14 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: If you run the command: [`npm prefix`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/prefix.html) from inside the template directory. What path does it print, is the path to the _template_ directory, or something else ?

Comment: git:(master) npm prefix
/Users/harshamv/Sites/skreem-html-v2